# Install all of google servies alcatel one touch fierce xl

Tags: rooting

I rooted my phone but after a while I realized google play store wasnt there. So I deleted the root app and did a factory reset but it didnt come back. So then I tried getting apks but when ever I tried to download something the app would just crash and when ever Im just using my phone a message would appear saying google play store has crashed. Is there anyway to restore my phone back to its former glory? Any answers please be explained in depth I dont understand some technical lingo

Comment: Once a system app is deleted, you can't get it back. You'll have to find a `gapps` package to flash to your phone or flash stock firmware to get the apk.

Answer (score 0):

root shouldn't delete the play store !

Did you do anything else ?

was it a dirty root zip 
( maybe ported from a new gapps installer as a base ?)
gapps is all i can tink of that would delete your store because it cleans up your old installation first, It sounds like someone made their own root.zip and used the script from gapps, thinking it'd just install root files into the system and not wipe anything...